# Correct MySQL configuration for Ruby on Rails Database.yml file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have this configuration:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql://127.0.0.1:3306' (1)
```

Is there something obvious that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You should separate the host from the port number.
You could have something, like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Comment: and host can't be `host: localhost`

Comment: For security reasons, it's generally considered bad practice to use `root` as the production database user. To set up a dedicated user for your rails app, see the [MySQL docs about user creation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html).

Comment: Also for security reasons (if you're using version control) you should not store your database password in `database.yml`. Instead, do what user3118220 did and get it from your environment: `password: ENV['MY_RAILS_APP_DB_PASSWORD']`.

Answer (score 23):

You also can do like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: root
  password:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_db_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_db_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production_db_name
```

Answer (score 4):

Use 'utf8mb4' as encoding to cover all unicode (including emojis)

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_bin
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_PASSWORD") %>
  host:     <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST") %>
```

([Reference1](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434))
([Reference2](https://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/))

Answer (score 2):

If you can have an empty config/database.yml file then define ENV['DATABASE_URL'] variable, then It will work

```
$ cat config/database.yml
 
$ echo $DATABASE_URL
mysql://root:my_password@127.0.0.1:3306/my_db_name
```

for Heroku:
heroku config:set `DATABASE_URL='mysql://root:my_password@host.com/my_db_name'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple databases for testing and development this might help

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: usr
  password: paswd
  shost: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: usr
  password: paswd
  shost: localhost
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: usr
  password: paswd
  shost: localhost
```

Comment: how is `shost` different than `host`?

Answer (score 0):

None of these anwers worked for me, I found **Werner Bihl**'s answer that fixed the problem.

[Getting "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'" error when setting up mysql database for Ruby on Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530089/getting-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mys)