# Rails Local Server Error: No such file database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project with another developer and I'm getting an error when trying to start my local server. Missing database.yml. I'm just using sqlite and another developer is using mongrel therefore I don't have a database.yml file. I'm not using Mongrel because I'm on ruby 1.9.2 and he is on ruby 1.8.7.

Is there a way to fix this error?

```
LIONIDAS:project robertb$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/robertb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:88:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/robertb/Sites/project/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: sqlite is a database and mongrel is a web server. So, why wouldn't you have database.yml file for that reason ?? And you are not using mongrel because you are using ruby 1.9.2 ? why is that ?? Getting confused with the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So still need add database.yml. You need one defining your SQLite Database.
Like so:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: If you're not using SQLite3 and you just copy this file, you'll get past this error and then into deep, dark hard to debug things (for me at lest). Don't just copy+past this if you're using another DB type, like MySQL. [Helpful info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872264/correct-mysql-configuration-for-ruby-on-rails-database-yml-file)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a different database configuration than the other developers of your project. Just add the **database.yml** to the **.gitignore** file. This is done automatically when generating a rails app and since the database.yml is missing on your machine that is already the case for your project too. So just create your personal **database.yml** file in the config folder of the app for your development environment.

Like this as minimal config:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

But Mongrel is not a database but a Web Server. Maybe the other developer is a using Mongo DB?

Answer (score 0):

Mongrel is a web server no?

You still need a database.yml file.