# Homebrew says "Warning: mysql-5.6.13 already installed" when trying to install mysql, but not visible in local gems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, homebrew

I saw that a mysql2 gem is installed, but no mysql. So I did a little `$ brew install mysql`, and I'm getting this warning:

`Warning: mysql-5.6.13 already installed`

**What should I do to remedy this?**

Here are the local gems(condensed of course):

```
 *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.13)
    net-scp (1.1.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that mysql is already installed on your machine. Try typing `which mysql` in your terminal (assuming you're on OSX) and you may have to add the result to your $PATH.

The mysql2 you're seeing is only a gem, which is not the same thing as mysql.

Comment: Seeing this: ``$ which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql`` Which I think is the right path. Do I still need to add it to my path? And if yes, how do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql

Comment: just into the terminal? would it be ``PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/mysql`` vs ``PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql`` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, Then try running the command mysql and you should be good to go. You may have to run mysql.server start to get the mysql server running.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it's good to go: ``$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1486
Server version: 5.1.43 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> 
``

Comment: Thanks,still only showing ``mysql2`` in ``gem list`` though. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Nope, you're good to go. The mysql2 gem is just an adapter. Once you're in mysql you can do CREATE DATABASE your_database_name; and make sure to modify your config/database.yml file to point to that database.

Comment: Ok great. I am still having an issue with creating the DB for my RoR project using ``rake db:setup``. I created a separate question, if you'd take a quick look I'd be super grateful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530089/getting-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mys

Comment: Answered the question over there.