# How to connect to mysqld in windows from rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Here i am trying to connect to mysql socket from rails in windows machine.
but i am not sure that this is the right way to connect to mysql socket.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: walden
  pool: 5
  username: walden
  password: w@1d3n
  socket: /XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

How can i connect to it.

Comment: Can't confirm because I don't have Windows, but pretty sure the Unix socket won't work and you need to connect through a TCP port, as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5872284/6678

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use sockets with Windows. Just remove the `socket` line from your config and everything should work fine.