# Getting Active records not found error when trying to configure database using mysql 5.7.1 with Rails 5 in windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RAILS and RUBY. I am trying to create a demo project to practice. When I was trying to configure my mysql database with RAILS, I got following error:

```
C:\Sites\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. 
Available: ["default", "adapter", "pool", "timeout", "database", "username", 
"password", "host"]

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Below is my database.yml file content

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
  default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: dumdum 
  password: dumdum
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default  

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I tried searching online but got no clear help.
I am running RAILS on WINDOWS 10

Answer (score 0):

before using rake db:schema:dump you have to create the database and then later you create tables,

to create database for your project

```
rake db:create
```

to create tables

```
rake db:migrate
```

after this you may be can check table schema using rake db:schema:dump

Answer (score 0):

I felt like you didn't indent your yaml file properly and therefore you the `development` cannot read the settings of `default`. Please try to indent it properly.

Another thing that I have noticed is that your port number is not set. I have updated the settings as follow by referring to [Correct MySQL configuration for Ruby on Rails Database.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872264/correct-mysql-configuration-for-ruby-on-rails-database-yml-file)

Please try the following and let me know:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  timeout: 5000
  username: dumdum 
  password: dumdum
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_production
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  yihyang. That really helped.
There were  issues:
1. default: &default indentation was not proper
2. gem file was not configured for mysql2

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

## Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

## config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: username #your mysql username
  password: password #your mysql password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_production
```

Then run command:

```
bundle

rake db:create

rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks  @puneet18. That really helped.
There were  issues:
1. default: &default indentation was not proper
2. gem file was not configured for mysql2