# How to use MySQL on Docker while developing a Rails project locally

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to use MySQL on Docker (instead of Homebrew) for a Rails project. This is because I need different versions of MySQL for each project, and it's a pain to switch versions with brew. However, I'm having trouble pointing Rails to the MySQL server on Docker.

I started the Docker container like this (`5.6` is the version I need):

```sh
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name project-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql_pw -d mysql:5.6
```

The container seems to be up and running fine, because

- `docker ps` tells me it is running
- I can connect to it via `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`

But I can't get Rails to create its DB in Docker; executing `rails db:setup` creates the DB in the locally installed MySQL instead.

I tried uninstalling MySQL locally with `brew uninstall mysql`, thinking perhaps it was somehow overriding the Docker one. But then, trying to set up the DB results in this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm not very familiar with Docker so I'm probably misunderstanding something. I googled around, but most of the information I could find was for Dockerizing the entire Rails project including MySQL, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: How is your Rails server run? On Docker or from your machine directly?

Comment: @PierreB. I run it from my machine directly (I use MacOS Catalina by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL instance is exposed on localhost via port 3306. You must configure Rails to use it, something like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Or by using environment variable:

```sh
export DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root:@127.0.0.1
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872264/correct-mysql-configuration-for-ruby-on-rails-database-yml-file) and [rails doc](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) for details

Currently you are trying to access MySQL via a socket at `/tmp/mysql.sock` but there is nothing available here as your MySQL instance runs into its container.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to edit `database.yml` because it's a team project, but your answer gave me an idea - in my environment variables, I tried setting up `DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root:@127.0.0.1/` and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, happy to help! I'll edit with this alternative solution (`DATABASE_URL` is also a supported way of doing this)